# How can I view the statements for all my inserts in SQL

Tags: sql, insert-statement

On SQL, I viewed the statements on creating the table, but now I need to view them for the inserts. Copy and pasting the actual statements are required for my assignment. The table is now completed, but I can't figure out on how to view the SQL statements on how I inserted my data. I took a screenshot.

The left side are the statements that I have already completed. Now I'm just missing one (Inserts). And the right side of the screen is my table. [image]

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Which tool/environment? SQL itself has no such functionality.

Comment: What do you mean by "view" the `INSERT`s? If you have them, you have written them. You can just view them in the editor you wrote them (or other for that matter), can't you?

Comment: There's no way to view them. What you should have done is run one, and when it succeeded, copy/pasted the code as needed before working on the next one.

Comment: Sorry Jarlh, I am using Apex Oracle. And thank you, Sticky bit, but unfortunately I am unable to do so. And, Ken White, that is exactly what I should have done. I am going to repeat the process and do exactly what you mentioned. Thank you all for your help.